# Doctrine add columns from a subquery

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I have the following code in SQL:

```
    SELECT id, SUM(horas) as horas , SUM(custo) as custo
FROM(
    SELECT mr.name, mr.id as id, SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(m.end, m.start))) as horas, SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(m.end, m.start))) * u.cost_hour as custo
    FROM meeting as m
    INNER JOIN meeting_join_rooms ON m.id = meeting_join_rooms.meeting_id
    INNER JOIN meeting_rooms mr ON meeting_join_rooms.meeting_room_id = mr.id
    INNER JOIN meeting_attendee ma ON ma.meeting_id = m.id
    INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = ma.user_id 
    WHERE m.cancel = false
    AND m.isMaster = false
    GROUP BY mr.name, u.id
) as subquery
GROUP BY name
```

I've converted the code to Doctrine using the following query builder:

```
$subquery = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select(' mr.name as name, SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(m.end, m.start))) as hours, SUM(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(m.end, m.start))) * users.costHour as cost')
            ->from('AppBundle:Meeting','m')
            ->join('m.meetingRooms', 'mr')
            ->join('m.participantUsers', 'ma')
            ->join('ma.user_id', 'users')
            ->join('users.groups', 'gu')
            ->where('m.cancel = false')
            ->andWhere('m.isMaster=false');

$totalHoursAndCost = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('SUM(hours) as y, SUM(cost) as totalCost')
            ->from( '## $subquery here ##')
            ->groupBy('name')->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

How do I sum the columns that result from a subquery in Doctrine?

Comment: You are not fetching entities from your database. Use SQL instead.

Comment: I also did in native SQL and it worked but I wanted to know if there is any way to do it in doctrine ...
Thank you!